# Measure size of Web Requests and Responses

Tags: asp.net, ajax, performance, request, response

I am looking for a way to measure the size of web requests and responses that I make in my browser. I would need a way to measure regular requests, as well as ajax requests. I am trying to improve Ajax performance by decreasing request and response size, and I need some way to benchmark this on the client end as well as measure my progress as I go.

This is part of an ASP.net application (3.5), but I would definitely prefer some client-based tool (Firefox plugin, executable application, etc) rather than a code-based approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [HttpWatch](http://www.httpwatch.com/) on IE and [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) on firefox to check the request response header. These should be enough for what you have asked for.

Answer (score 3):

I usually use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to investigate what requests that are made, response times and sizes.

Answer (score 1):

[Yahoo! YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) add-on for Firebug (in FireFox) is one of the best tool for what you want to do.

EDIT: You'll need [FireBug](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/1843) installed in Firefox first to install YSlow.

Answer (score 1):

For firefox there is a add-on available called [LORI](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1743) (Life-Of-Request-Information).

It tells you the pagesize, how many request it makes to server(for css, javascript etc.) time to first byte and time to completion of the request.

Answer (score 1):

For internet explorer you can download IE Developer toolbar from:
"http://www.microsoft.com/DownLoads/details.aspx?familyid=E59C3964-672D-4511-BB3E-2D5E1DB91038&displaylang=en"

Additionally you can download Fiddler from:
"http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/"

To profile your request/response.

For Firefox there are numerous plugins:
- Firebug
- YSlow

Answer (score 1):

In addition to everyone else's excellent recommendations there's a specific toolset for Visual Studio and Ajax, the [VS Ajax Profiling Extensions](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/AjaxView) - however this will only work on IIS7

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Firefox Firebug plugin > [Network Monitoring](http://getfirebug.com/net.html) might do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Charles is an excellent web debugging proxy that will show you the size of every HTTP request made by your web browser.  It also offers a very easy way to examine the payload of your requests, including XML.

http://www.charlesproxy.com/